Header and footer is not taking full width
The header and footer works fine in laptop screen. But when I turn on responsive screen and test it in different width, the header and footer both decreases in width. What I want is that when I reduce the width of the screen the header and footer should still take 100% width of the screen like it is supposed to.


body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.left {
    line-height: 0.8;
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    font-family: "Shadows Into Light", cursive;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: none;
}

.left-title {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:2rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #3C4242;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.link {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3C4242;
    font-size: large;
}

.link:hover{
    color: #0d0d0d;
}

.right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 3rem;
}

.person {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin:0 1rem 0 1rem
}

.cart {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.footer{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #3C4242;
    color: #F6F6F6;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.info {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.info > div > p{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.social {
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    align-content: center;
}

.icons > div > span {
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: 5rem;
}

.download > h1 {
    line-height: 0.5;
}

.copyright {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class='left'>
            <p class='left-title'>
                test Store
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class='middle'>
            <a class="link" href="/">Shop</a>
            <a class="link" href="/">Men</a>
            <a class="link" href="/">Women</a>
            <a class="link" href="/">Combos</a>
        </div>
        <div class='right'>
            <span>search</span>
            <span class="cart">cart</span>
            <span class="person">person</span>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>test page</main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class='info'>
            <div>
              <h1>Need Help</h1>
              <p>Contact Us</p>
              <p>Track Order</p>
              <p>FAQ's</p>
              <p>Career</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Company</h1>
              <p>About Us</p>
              <p>Euphoria Blog</p>
              <p>Collaboration</p>
              <p>Media</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>More Info</h1>
              <p>Terms and Conditions</p>
              <p>Privacy Policy</p>
              <p>Shipping Policy</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Location</h1>
              <h5>support@euphoria.com</h5>
              <h5>Banani, Dhaka, Bangladesh</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class='icons'>
            <div className='social'>
              <span>icon</span>
              <span>icon</span>
              <span>icon</span>
            </div>
            <div class='download'>
              <h1>Download The App</h1>
              <span>icon</span>
              <span>icon</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='copyright'><span>Copyright © 2024 Euphoria Ltd. All rights reserved</span></div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>



I tried using media query but it is not working

But when I turn on responsive screen and test it in different width, the header and footer both decreases in width. .. that's not clear enough. I mean if you reduce the screen width, header and footer of course reduce their width accordingly still occupying 100%. By the way header and footer are ok.. but they are containers and their content (especially the header) has elements with display grid. I think you should better focus the question

@DiegoD Yes, I think you are correct. The width is decreasing correctly. The issue is happening due to overflow in header

yes of course.. but indeed the container is 100%.. its content is overflow.. but clipping the overflow is not responsive.. it's just hiding the problem. To make it responsive you need media queries that will style those content items in a different way so that they won't occupy space (or less space)

@DiegoD I will add media query and a hamburger menu for responsiveness. It's just I did not understand overflow problem before. I have added a lot of margin left and right in header which is causing this overflow problem

The issue occurs because the header is overflowing. To fix this, you just need to add the flex-wrap: wrap; property to both the header and footer. but don't forget to make the header responsive for mobile sizes :) .
overflow: hidden; /* Added to ensure content is contained */



body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Added to ensure content is contained */

}

.left {
    line-height: 0.8;
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    font-family: "Shadows Into Light", cursive;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: none;
}

.left-title {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:2rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #3C4242;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.link {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3C4242;
    font-size: large;
}

.link:hover{
    color: #0d0d0d;
}

.right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 3rem;
}

.person {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin:0 1rem 0 1rem
}

.cart {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.footer{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #3C4242;
    color: #F6F6F6;
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow: hidden; /* Added to ensure content is contained */
}

.info {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.info > div > p{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.social {
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    align-content: center;
}

.icons > div > span {
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: 5rem;
}

.download > h1 {
    line-height: 0.5;
}

.copyright {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
} 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class='left'>
            <p class='left-title'>
                test Store
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class='middle'>
            <a class="link" href="/">Shop</a>
            <a class="link" href="/">Men</a>
            <a class="link" href="/">Women</a>
            <a class="link" href="/">Combos</a>
        </div>
        <div class='right'>
            <span>search</span>
            <span class="cart">cart</span>
            <span class="person">person</span>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>test page</main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class='info'>
            <div>
              <h1>Need Help</h1>
              <p>Contact Us</p>
              <p>Track Order</p>
              <p>FAQ's</p>
              <p>Career</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Company</h1>
              <p>About Us</p>
              <p>Euphoria Blog</p>
              <p>Collaboration</p>
              <p>Media</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>More Info</h1>
              <p>Terms and Conditions</p>
              <p>Privacy Policy</p>
              <p>Shipping Policy</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Location</h1>
              <h5>support@euphoria.com</h5>
              <h5>Banani, Dhaka, Bangladesh</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class='icons'>
            <div className='social'>
              <span>icon</span>
              <span>icon</span>
              <span>icon</span>
            </div>
            <div class='download'>
              <h1>Download The App</h1>
              <span>icon</span>
              <span>icon</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='copyright'><span>Copyright © 2024 Euphoria Ltd. All rights reserved</span></div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>




it's quite odd that clipping the header was a valid answer... @Extra_Caterpillar your ideas about responsive design are pretty confused

@DiegoD I was thinking the problem was in responsive design. But It turned out something else. Thanks for the help by the way

the problem is still responsive design.. you just didn't address it correctly. So when the screen is shorter now those links in the menu won't be accessible.. you are doing it wrong!

@DiegoD this is not permanent solution. he should do hamburger-menu for the mobile and shorter screens. but if he wrap it for now using flex-wrap: wrap it's gonna handle it for the time.

I was just trying to point out that it was not a solution to the problem. The problem was badly asked and badly addressed in the answer. Highlighting the overflow hidden was just a comment.. it was not a solution. In the end the overflow hidden will be gone anyway. But the OP couldn't face the nuance of its own issue and killed the question by accepting the answer. Anyway the ambiguity and all its consequences began from the question itself. (ps.: the flex wrap came later and still is patching the oddities hiding the fact it's bad designed to begin with)

The contents in your header section is overflowing.
since you are using flexbox. a simple way to avoid this problem is by using
flex-wrap: wrap; 
for all the overflowing div's.  but this is not ideal solution. you are better to use hamburger menu for smaller screens.
